# How to add same type of panel having same type of controls at runtime in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a form named 'add child'.
In that form i dropped a combobox from which user can choose no of childern he/she is having.
Initially there is a panel  containing a textbox to get the name of child, 3 combobox to get the day month and year of date of birth of child and one more box for the blood group of child.
Now what i want is as the user choose its number of child  the same panel get added at runtime one below the other depending upon the number choosen.

i know that to simply add a control we code like this

```
 private void addchildbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
```

and what to do if we have to add a same type of panel containing same elements one below the other.
I had done this codding which is wrong

```
private void addchildbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            childpnl pnl = new childpnln();

            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }
```

Also i want to submit the data to the database through the controls added on run time.
So how to name these controls to do the codding of database.
Please help

Comment: yes.....actually i dont know how to do this as i am a beginner  @Yatrix

Comment: I gave you an answer below, but if you're a beginner, you may not understand it all just yet. You'll have to do some research on how to do all of those things, but that's part of programming. You spend a lot of time Googling. =) Errors will appear in the Errors Window, which you can open in the View menu in Visual Studio. You'll want to Google the error you're given to get a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: is childpnl a user control you created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public int childrenCount; //The number of children

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //Adds a child
        childrenCount++;
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.Location = new Point(10, (childrenCount - 1) * 200);
        p.Width = 300;
        p.Height = 200;
        p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        TextBox tName = new TextBox(); //TextBox for the name
        tName.Location = new Point(200, 20);
        tName.Text = "name";
        MonthCalendar calendar = new MonthCalendar(); //Calendar to choose the birth date
        TextBox bloodGroup = new TextBox(); //TextBox for the blood group
        bloodGroup.Location = new Point(200, 50);
        bloodGroup.Text = "blood group";
        p.Controls.Add(tName);
        p.Controls.Add(calendar);
        p.Controls.Add(bloodGroup);
        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //Checks the values
        string message = "";
        foreach(Control c in this.Controls) { //loop throught the elements of the form
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel)) { //check if the control is a Panel
                //Get the values from the input fields and add it to the message string
                Panel p = (Panel)c;
                TextBox tName = (TextBox)(c.Controls[0]);
                MonthCalendar calendar = (MonthCalendar)(c.Controls[1]);
                TextBox bloodGroup = (TextBox)(c.Controls[2]);
                message += tName.Text + ":\n";
                message += "birth date: " + calendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString() + "\n";
                message += "blood group: " + bloodGroup.Text + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        //show the message string in a MessageBox
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

example:

If you add a child called Jack, birth date April the 28. 2013 and blood group A+, the result will be following:

**Jack:**

**birth date: 28.4.2013**

**blood group: A+**

(Note, the date string can change if you have an other culture)

Comment: thank u dear thank alot.... it is working properly, the only problem is with location  that i am trying to solve myself thanks again thank u so so so much

Answer (score 0):

Adding a panel that way looks correct. There may be something else that's causing a problem. WIthout an error, it's hard to say.

As for the second part, if you want to submit data to the database from your controls, don't handle the database code inside the code. Create a data access layer to handle your database calls.

Give your user controls either public properties you can retrieve the data from or create a model that you can have passed back from a function or property on the user control. This model should then be used in conjunction with your Data Access Layer to update the database as required.

Have your main form or your main form's model (or a controller class if you went that route) coordinate the data management from the controls to the DAL to the Db.

Comment: can please give me the helping code to slve this problem...please

Comment: i have not yet done any codding in this new form added as i dont know anything about it

Comment: What I just suggested is entirely too much code to write. I'd be writing your program for you, which is not what this site is for. This site isn't to teach people how to program, but to help with specific code problems. You need to learn to program on your own. Look at .NET tutorials, buy a book and use the MSDN.

Comment: ok friend thank  but i dont need the full program i just need a helping code to add the same panel with same controls at the runtime thats all

Comment: If you created a user control, you should just be able to add it to the controls collection. `this.controls.add(new ucMyPanel());`

Comment: and how to create data access layer

Comment: @user2327043 If you found my answer helpful, be sure to upvote it and accept it. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @user2327043 DAL tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188750.aspx